# How to predict individual coefficients and residuals with unbalanced panel data

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I have a panel data with income for individuals over years, and I am interested in the income trends of individuals, and unexpected changes in income (i.e individual coefficients for income over years, and residuals for each individual for each year). However, I have a lot of observations with missing income data at least for one or more years, so with a linear regression I lose the majority of my observations. I was thinking about doing a multiple imputation and then running a linear regression. However, I was told that maximum likelihood is a better approach for predicting the missing data in my case, instead of multiple imputation, as I would be over-weighting my observed data. I was thinking about doing a random effects model which does not delete observations due to missing measurements for few years, and which I think is using a maximum likelihood approach. However, Hausman test gave an significant result, thus I had to use fixed effects model. With this model, I was able to get residuals, but not individual income coefficients over years. My understanding of fixed effect model is that it assumes the coefficient is the same for every unit but intercepts change for different units.

My main question is what would be the best approach in my case to predict individual income coefficients (slopes) and the divergences from individual income trends (residuals); and is using a FE model makes sense in my case? The answer to these questions would help me a lot.

To give an idea of my data structure:

```
caseid<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4)
years<-c(1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,
1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008,1998,2000,2002,2004,2006,2008)
income<-c(1100,NA,NA,NA,NA,1300,1500,1900,2000,NA,2200,NA, 
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, 2300,2500,2000,1800,NA, 1900)
df<-data.frame(caseid, years, income)
```

And my model in R was:

```
inc.fe<-plm(Income~Year, data=df, model="within", effect="individual")
```

Thanks a lot